# How to configure simple_form to show validation status

Tags: css, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have simple css:

```
form.submitted span::after { content: ' ✓'; }
```

- should display ✓ when field is valid after submitting the form

Style below overrides above, when field is invalid:

```
form.submitted span.error::after { content: ' ⨉'; }
```

The problem is that simple form not generating .span or any other selector, when the form field is valid.

How to realise this functionality in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find some solution:

I add missing span selectors dynamically:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("form.submitted div.input").each ->
    if $(this).find("span.error").length is 0
      row_str = "<span class=\"valid\"></span>"
      $(this).append row_str
```

And now looks like:

[image]